# Can you attack again with a natural weapon using Improved Trip?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, natural-weapon, trip

Normally you can only attack once in a round with a natural weapon, regardless of BAB. However, Improved Trip grants an extra attack outside of BAB with a successful trip; could you make that attack with a natural weapon you've already used that turn?

Example: a character with a bite attack, the Trip special attack (free trip attempt on a hit with bite attack), and the Improved Trip feat. They hit with the bite and successfully trip; could they make the free attack with their bite attack too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can make your free attack from Improved Trip with a natural weapon you have already used that round.

There's no ironclad rule that you can only attack once in a round with a given natural weapon.  The rule you're probably thinking of is that you don't get extra attacks with natural weapons *from having high Base Attack Bonus*, the way you get iterative attacks with manufactured weapons.  From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm):

> Creatures do not receive additional attacks from a high base attack bonus when using natural weapons.

This rule does not prevent creatures from attacking multiple times with a single natural weapon if they find some way of doing so *other* than iterative attacks from high BAB.  Possibilities include:

- The Rapidstrike and Improved Rapidstrike feats from Draconomicon
- Having the ability to take multiple attack actions in a single round, like from the Shadow Pounce ability provided by Telflammar Shadowlord (Unapproachable East)
- Taking an attack of opportunity in a round when you have already attacked
- Getting extra attacks from the [Cleave](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#cleave) feat

The free attack from Improved Trip is an extra, triggered attack like those listed above - you're free to take it with any weapon, including a natural weapon that's already attacked.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind Improved Trip for a moment. If a creature has the Trip special ability, and only has one natural attack, how would it make the trip attempt after a successful attack if it could not use the same natural weapon? ([Wolf](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/wolf.htm), for example.)

Comment: In case of a wolf it effectively substitutes its regular attack for usual touch attack made before trip attempt itself. Its not like making two attacks. Its like people make touch attack + trip attempt as a consequence of that initial touch attack, and wolfs make regular attack + trip attempt as a consequence of their initial non-touch attack. So I think your reasoning is false here.

Comment: (One of the things my groups missed *for years* was that the wolf's extraordinary ability trip "can attempt to trip the opponent… *as a free action*" (emphasis mine) so that it can't use that ability off-turn like during an attack of opportunity. Just sayin'.)

Comment: Well, I think it does. I'll leave my comment as a thing to consider for people examining your answer.

Comment: @annoyingimp - If there is anything in the text that leads to your description, I certainly don't see it. It's an interesting way to look at it, but the text clearly describes a *second free action*.  If they were the same action, then why mention free? Or is this some other interpretation of what a free action is?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83373/about-trip-ex).

Comment: As written, a wolf can drag down a foe when it can devote its whole attention to the task (i.e. on its turn), yet it can only bite a foe—and *not* drag it down—when the foe makes a combat error (i.e. during an attack of opportunity).  To me, that seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: @HeyICanChan For that matter grapple also requires free action to initiate opposed grapple checks (hold). I don't think authors included it in things you may do as an AoO just to let you waste one. At least some free actions may be taken out of turn after all.

Comment: @annoyingimp That *free action* part was added to grapple upon the *3.5* revision—with that in mind, I'd argue that it totally *is* intentional that creatures be largely unable to grapple during attacks of opportunity, text trumping the table as the saying goes. So far as I'm aware, the only *free action* that can explicitly be taken off-turn is speaking, and even that creates a number of problems. (Speaking should really be a nonaction.) See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33301/8610), its answer getting me called a [neckbeard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37637/8610).

Comment: Yes, but, to be even clearer, I'd note that the *free* part isn't the only difference between them. That is, I'm also stating that two different abilities are allowed to function differently. `:-)`

Comment: I struggle to see the inconsistency. Attacks of opportunity aren't given an action type by [Actions in Combat](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#actions-in-combat), and [the free attack granted by an attack of opportunity doesn't require the creature to take a *free action* to make it](http://dndsrd.net/initiativeAndAoO.html#attacks-of-opportunity).

Comment: Who knows intent at this point? All I know is that grapple, improved grab, and trip really do say *as a free action.* It's not *just* the word *free* limiting them but also the word *action*. The feats Cleave, Great Cleave, and Improved Trip use *entirely different* language. I mean, *as a free action* is just simply *not the same* as, for example, Improved Trip saying, "If you trip an opponent in melee combat, you immediately get a melee attack against that opponent as if you hadn’t used your attack for the trip attempt." Different things do different things. [*Shrugs.*]